# C# Entityframework core 2.1 query not including where condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My following query is not including the where condition in sql query plan.

```
var userStandby = await _context.UserStandby
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(standBy => ECUserId.Equals(standBy.ECUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

i am using EF Core 2.1 and the UserStandby table has got 12500 records.
I am getting timeout error as the query is not including the where condition.

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this?

thanks

Comment: EF might not be able to translate that C# into SQL properly. It's likely you'll need to use something like ```EF.Functions.Like```.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
var userStandby = await _context.UserStandby
                                .Where(standBy => ECUserId.Equals(standBy.ECUserId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

You put your condition in the Where expression and with firstordefault you say that you want only 1 result or null.